# DB2 Build special select

Tags: sql, db2, greatest-n-per-group, db2-luw

I have a table with multipe primary keys `ID` and `ANUMBER`.

| ID (PK) | ANUMBER (PK) | NAME | OPTION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | true |
| 1 | 2 | B | true |
| 1 | 3 | C | false |
| 2 | 1 | AA | true |

So what I want to get by the `Select` is

| ID (PK) | ANUMBER (PK) | NAME | OPTION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | true |

OR

| ID (PK) | ANUMBER (PK) | NAME | OPTION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | B | true |

I not know if it is possible to build such a `Select`.

Precondition is that the `ID` should be equal and `Option` is `true` and it does not matter which row is returned, one row is sufficient, thats why I listed above two results which are valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the `group by` and `having` clauses, and since it doesn't matter which row is returned, you can use `min()` or `max()`:

```
select ID, MAX(ANUMBER) as ANUMBER, MAX(NAME) as NAME, 'true' AS OPTION
from mytable
where OPTION = 'true'
group by ID
having sum(case when OPTION = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) > 1
```

If the *OPTION* is `boolean` then try this :

```
select ID, MAX(ANUMBER) as ANUMBER, MAX(NAME) as NAME, 'true' AS OPTION
from mytable
where OPTION
group by ID
having sum(case when OPTION then 1 else 0 end) > 1
```

If you don't want to list all of the columns, you can use the window functions `row number()` and the cumulative `sum()`:

```
with cte as (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by id order by ANUMBER desc) rn, 
            sum(case when OPTION then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by id order by ANUMBER ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as count_
  from mytable
  where OPTION
)
select *
from cte c
where rn = 1 and COUNT_ > 1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/np6yIT4t)

Comment: Ok works, but when I have several columns (which I actually have), these should be listed in the `group by`. But the filter should be on the `ID`.
Is their any alternative solution.

Comment: Ok, can you check my edit

Comment: Both solutions are working with `partition`, Thx both @GMB, @ 
SelVazi.
At least, is it possible to say here 
`select *
from cte c ...` only to output the rows of the set above from `select *` and not `rn` and `count_`