# DB2 Selective Select

Tags: db2, db2-luw

Is it possible `select` only the columns from the base table without list all the columns, meaning all columns wihout `rn` column.

This will not work...

```
select tt.t.*
from (
```

**Origin:**

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by anumber) rn 
    from mytable t 
    where option
) tt
where rn = 1
order by id
```

Comment: No that's not possible in DB2. You have to enumerate the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76180588/db2-build-special-select) :

You can do it by joining the subquery with your table :

```
select t.*
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by anumber) rn    
    from mytable t 
    where option
) tt
inner join mytable t on t.ID = tt.ID and t.ANUMBER = tt.ANUMBER
where rn = 1
order by t.id
```